# Force apps to open in current screen - OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor set-up on my mac mini running OSX 10.9 Mavericks.  All is running very smoothly but I hate the fact that when I have the dock in one of the monitors and click on an app it opens in the last screen it lived in rather than the current screen, or a fixed home.

Is there any way to either:

1 - Assign a monitor to an app permanently, say I always want Mail to open in the left monitor and Xcode to open in the right monitor...

or

2 - Make all apps open in the monitor they were opened in (ie the one which is currently active)

I've searched as best I can for an answer to this to no avail so any help on either/both of the above is more than welcome.

One other question... is there a way to assign which monitor assumes primary responsibility (eg where my desktop icons appear).  I have been trying a few monitors out and now that I have settled on the two I want the 'wrong' one always has my desktop on it.  If I disconnect it then they shift to the right one, but as soon as I reconnect it again it seems to take over as primary again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To assign a app, you first must have multiple desktops running in mission control.

1. Make a new desktop in mission control.
2. Launch the app you want to assign and put it on the screen you want it to be assigned to.
3. Right-click or ctrl-click on the dock icon for the app.
4. Go to options.
5. You should now see the option to assign to desktop of display 1, display 2, etc...

Enjoy.